# How to take a portion of one column to match with a portion of another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean up a large dataset. A sample of the dataset shows:

```
         Player Name        Headline    
0        LeBron James       Woj: NBA. ESPN planning for a H-O-R-S-E tourna...
1        LeBron James       LeBron James suggests 5-10 games before playoffs
2        LeBron James       LeBron James overcomes Pelicans with 34/13/12
3        LeBron James       Anthony Davis (knee) won't play on Sunday
...      ...                ...
105180   Ryan Anderson      Ryan Anderson has first career double-double
105181   Ryan Anderson      Yi says he'll be back after All-Star break
105182   Ryan Anderson      Anderson stays hot in Nets win
```

The problem I am having is that some headlines do not have anything to do with the player name (as you can see in row 0, 3, and 105181).

**Question:**

Is there a way to clean up the data so a portion of the "Player Name" column is featured in the "Headline" column? The rest that don't match would be removed from the new dataset made.

**For example:**

Row 0 would be removed since "LeBron" or "James" isn't in the "Headline" column.

Row 1 and 2 would stay the same.

Row 3 would be removed since "LeBron" or "James" isn't in the "Headline" column.

Row 105180 would stay the same.

Row 105181 would be removed since "Ryan" or "Anderson" isn't in the "Headline" column.

Row 105182 would stay the same since "Anderson" is in the "Player Name" and "Headline" column.

The new dataset will feature only the filtered data that has a portion of the "Player Name" column in the "Headline" column. I didn't know if there was a way to do this or if `str.split` should be used on the "Headline" column to split up the name from the rest of the headline then clean up from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on each cell of the `Player Name` column and run an `in` check for each of the split words on the corresponding `Headline`. If [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) pass the `in` test, keep the row.

```
def any_words_included(x):
    return any(y in x["Headline"] for y in x["Player Name"].split())

df = df[df.apply(any_words_included, axis=1)]
```

Provide the kwarg `axis=1` to [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to filter on rows.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function and apply it to each row, like this:

```
def keep_headlines(row):
    first = row['Player Name'].split()[0]
    last = row['Player Name'].split()[1]
    if (first in row['Headline']) | (last in row['Headline']):
        return 1 
    else:
        return 0
```

you can then apply this function using apply method:

```
df['mask'] = df.apply(keep_headlines, axis=1)
df = df[df['mask'] == 1]
```

then you can drop the "mask" column.

```
df.drop(columns='mask', inplace=True)
```

I hope this answer helps you!

Comment: Welcome! What is the `keep_headline`? I am getting `NameError: name 'keep_headline' is not defined`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. just change add "s" in the name of the function inside apply method.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df['exists'] = df.apply(lambda x: any([k in x['Headline'] for k in x['Player Name'].split()]), axis=1)
df = df[~df['exists']==False].drop(columns=['exists'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     Player Name                                          Headline
1   LeBron James  LeBron James suggests 5-10 games before playoffs
2   LeBron James     LeBron James overcomes Pelicans with 34/13/12
4  Ryan Anderson      Ryan Anderson has first career double-double
6  Ryan Anderson                    Anderson stays hot in Nets win
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work properly. In your example: Row 0, Lebron or James isn't in the Headline column. This would mean this row should be removed. Row 3 and 5 should be removed as well since there is no portion of "Player Name" in the "Headline column. Row 6 works.

Comment: Missed that part, fixing it

Comment: `== False` is unidiomatic, is it really necessary here?

Comment: That's because the condition is inverted. It seems roundabout to create a new column only to drop it--we can filter with the predicate directly (see the accepted answer). As a really minor aside `any([...])` is an antipattern because it generates the entire list. Doing `any(...)` (that is, passing in a generator) means that you get an early bailout as soon as the predicate is true. Of course it hardly matters with two elements.

Comment: Yep that’s definitely a better way. This is roundabout, agreed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `groupby` as you seem to have several times the same player and then [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) on the name of the player once `split` to get either part of the name.

```
df_ = df[df.groupby('Player Name')
           .apply(lambda x: x['Headline'].str.contains('|'.join(x.name.split(' '))))
           .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)]
print (df_)
          Player Name                                          Headline

1        LeBron James  LeBron James suggests 5-10 games before playoffs
2        LeBron James     LeBron James overcomes Pelicans with 34/13/12
105180  Ryan Anderson      Ryan Anderson has first career double-double
105182  Ryan Anderson                    Anderson stays hot in Nets win
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not make any changes in the dataframe.

Comment: The output `df_` didn't filter out the data on my end. I am still getting "Headlines" that do not have a portion of the "Player Name" when I run this code.

Comment: What is the `to_numpy()` for?

Comment: @Sunny I edited the code with `reset_index` instead of `to_numpy`, in the example data, it did not change anything but on the full data it does

Comment: _and it is the error here actually, it prevents index alignment_ Ah alright, that's the part I wasn't sure about.